# OpenPOP.POP3 with IIS SSL certificate

Tags: .net, email, pop3, .net-3.5

I am using OpenPOP
I am trying to retrieve mail from an in office exchange server. This is my code

```
 popClient.Connect(host.Host, (int)host.Port, (bool)host.Ssl);
 popClient.Authenticate(host.Username, host.Password);
```

Prodlem is the SSL Certificate is created in iis 7 and isnt a valid certificate is there any way for my to bypass this.

It gives me the error  remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. It requires some small code changes is the POPClient class.

**Step 1**: Replace the constructor for the SslStream instance that is used to authenticate the server with one that allows you to provide a delegate for validating the certificate supplied by the remote party. Therefore replace

```
SslStream stream = new SslStream(clientSocket.GetStream(), false);
```

from POPClient class, Connect method with

```
SslStream stream = new SslStream(clientSocket.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
```

**Step 2**: Provide the method that is called by the delegate and force the validation of the remote certificate by returning always true:

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{         
    return true;  // force the validation of any certificate
}
```

For further details on this subject, please check the documentation available on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix, pointed me in the right direction. OpenPOP now has an overload that supports this.

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the developers on OpenPop. I had not thought of a use for this, but seeing this is an issue I will put it into the main code when I have the time for it and not working on some other parts of it. It is on my TODO list as of now.

/Kasper (foens)

Comment: This has now been implemented in the new version of OpenPop.NET.